# How many events are stored in my PredictionIO event server?

Tags: apache-spark, predictionio

I imported an unknown number of events into my PIO eventserver and now I want to know that number (in order to measure and compare recommendation engines). I could not find an API for that, so I had a look at the MySQL database my server uses. I found two tables:

```
mysql> select count(*) from pio_event_1;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  6371759 |
+----------+
1 row in set (8.39 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from pio_event_2;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  2018200 |
+----------+
1 row in set (9.79 sec)
```

Both tables look very similar, so I am still unsure.

*Which table is relevant? What is the difference between pio_event_1 and pio_event_2?*

*Is there a command or REST API where I can look up the number of stored events?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go through the spark shell, described in the [troubleshooting docs](https://docs.prediction.io/customize/troubleshooting/)

Launch the shell with

```
pio-shell --with-spark
```

Then find all events for your app and count them

```
import io.prediction.data.store.PEventStore
PEventStore.find(appName="MyApp1")(sc).count
```

You could also filter to find different subsets of events by passing more parameters to find. See the [api docs](https://docs.prediction.io/api/current/#io.prediction.data.store.PEventStore$) for more details. The [LEventStore](https://docs.prediction.io/api/current/#io.prediction.data.store.LEventStore$) is also an option

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks! BTW, the number turned out to be 2018200, the count of rows in table *pio_event_2*.

Comment: glad to help, I don't know the difference between the two MySQL tables either

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your database

```
\c db_name
```

List tables

```
\dt;
```

Run query

```
select count(*) from pio_event_1;
```

PHP

```
<?php
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=db_name user=postgres");

$result = pg_query($dbconn, "select count(*) from pio_event_1");
if (!$result) {
    echo "An error occurred.\n";
    exit;
}

// Not the best way, but output the total number of events. 
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo '<P><center>'.number_format($row[0]) .' Events</center></P>';
}  ?>
```

Comment: While this is a valid answer to the question, it would be helpful for other people than the OP (mainly for future visitors of this thread) to add some explanation what your code actually does.